# How is it possible that accessing a lateinit var can cause NullPointerException in a kotlin android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I got a crash from firebase crashlytics that says:

```
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.oopsbot/org.healroot.widget.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.healroot.widget.repository.CoordinateRepository org.healroot.widget.dependency.RepositoryProvider.authenticationRepository()

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.healroot.widget.repository.AuthenticationRepository org.healroot.widget.dependency.RepositoryProvider.authenticationRepository()' on a null object reference
       at org.healroot.widget.core.base.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.kt:13)
       at org.healroot.widget.core.base.BaseActivity.<init>(BaseActivity.kt:1)
       at org.healroot.widget.ui.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:1)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java)
       at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
       at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1273)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3679)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3949)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:106)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2327)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
```

I did skip some code, changed names, etc as I'm not allowed to show that, but here's the code that I think is relevant to the crash.

```
object HealrootWidget{

    private lateinit var repoProvider: RepositoryProvider
    private lateinit var application: Application

    internal fun repoProvider() = repoProvider


    @JvmStatic
    fun startWidget(
        application: Application,
    ) {
        initialize(application)

        val intent = LoadingActivity.createIntent(
            context,
            requestId,
            oneTimeToken
        )
        intent.flags += Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun initialize(
        application: Application
    ) {
        repoProvider = RepositoryProvider(context, widgetAliveObserver, environment)
    }
}
```

Here is where the crash happens:

```
internal abstract class BaseActivity<B : ViewBinding>() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val authRepo: AuthenticationRepository = repoProvider().authenticationRepository()

}
```

RepositoryProvider:

```
internal class RepositoryProvider(
        context: Context,
        widgetAliveObserver: WidgetAliveObserver,
        env: HealrootEnvironment
    ) {
    
        private val database: HealrootDatabase by lazy {
            val builder =
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, HealrootDatabase::class.java, "${env.name}_$DB_NAME")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    
            val passphrase = BuildConfig.SQLITE_CIPHER_PASSPHRASE.toCharArray()
            val factory = SupportFactory(SQLiteDatabase.getBytes(passphrase))
            builder.openHelperFactory(factory)
    
            builder.build()
        }
    
        private val authenticationRepository = AuthenticationRepositoryImpl(
            database.tokenDao(),
            widgetAliveObserver
        )
    
        fun authenticationRepository(): AuthenticationRepository = authenticationRepository
    
        companion object {
            private const val DB_NAME = "database.db"
        }
    }
```

I haven't been able to reproduce this crash myself in any way.

The widget is launched from my client's applications, about which I have no knowledge about or control over.

Seeing how this crash happens when instantiating MainActivity class, it means that RepositoryProvider and authentication repository have been accessed and used already by LoadingActivity.

Here's how the intent for MainActivity is created:

```
fun createIntent(context: Context, step: WidgetStep) =
    Intent(
        context,
        MainActivity::class.java
    ).apply {
        flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        putExtra(EXTRA_WIDGET_STEP, step)
    }
```

Please feel free to ask questions if you feel that these details are incomplete.

Comment: Disable background processes in the android developer settings. Then start your app and widget, suspend it, open another app so that your app's process is killed by the OS. Then open your app again. Does this reproduce the crash?

Comment: To add more information to my previous suggestion: When your app is in the background, its process can be killed by Android. When a user opens the app again, it starts from the last activity. All data and variables which were not persisted will be then wiped. So your app starts fresh from MainActivity without opening LoadActivity first.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Shouldn't it be throwing UninitializedPropertyAccessException in that case?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann I did as you told and It does cause a crash at that exact same place with almost the same log except it's `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property repoProvider has not been initialized` and not null pointer exception.